# Best way to manage string resources in Android

Tags: android

I am recently learning Android app development and met string resources. Then I start thinking to hold some warning message in resources XML for `Toast.makeText`, so that I can utilize the native i18n feature. But then I find that even with a small app, there might be many messages and can easily drain the resource name.

Here is my question:

1. Is using string resources to hold error messages is a bad idea?
2. How do those huge projects manage those string resources? Load over network or something else.

I found many posts only talking about how to use the string resources (with `R.string.foobar`), but not for experience sharing. Please share some of your experience, thank you in advance.

ps. Is there any way to separate resources, like an XML file for this activity and another for that, etc?

Comment: String resources makes your app easily localized, which by itself worth the while. Our team uses www.localise.biz to manage all strings. We have a script to fetch the translations during build (or manually) so all the management is done in their web app.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong in storing error messages in resource you can go ahead and store generic error messages. When it comes to strings you need to differentiate between static and dynamic strings. Static means Screen titles app names which don't change often dynamic is more about content. For Dynamic you can pass parameter indicating current selected language when making api call and let api handle the response language. you can also build service for this

Comment: @gioravered localize.biz sounds like an interesting idea to me, I had never heard of such kind of service.